# Node.js sftp putfile not creating directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to upload files using Node.js but it is not able to create directory. Please suggest what is wrong in my code:

```
var Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
var sftp = new Client();

sftp.connect({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: '22',
    username: 'username',
    password: '****'
}).then(() => {
    glob(dir.replace(/\/$/, '') + '/**/**', function(err, files) {
        files.forEach(function(file){
            var serverF = file.replace(dir, '');
            console.log('**** ',cred.path+serverF, '==', file);
            //sftp.mkdir(file, true);
            sftp.put(file, cred.path+serverF, true);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That module does not support creating directories implicitly. You will have to create them yourself in one way or another.